# How to get date of creation of Wikipedia page by API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

Wikipedia article [United States presidential election, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2016) has [page information](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=United_States_presidential_election,_2016&action=info) which contains *"Date of page creation"* under *"Edit history"* section. How do I get this date through an API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this goal you need to use action [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) with property [revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=timestamp&rvdir=newer&titles=United States presidential election, 2016
```

where:

- **rvdir=newer** - sort revisions by oldest first
- **rvlimit=1** - get only one revision (the 1st one)
- **rvprop=timestamp** - get only information about the revision timestamp

In your case the result will be: `"2009-02-03T09:59:37Z"` → `09:59, 3 February 2009`.